# AlertDialog will not close

Tags: java, android

I have an alert dialog, which offers the user two options: `yes` and `no`. When `no` is selected it the `AlertDialog` closes but when `yes` is selected it takes the user online to give them directions but when I go back to the application the `AlertDialog` is still visible and I can't seem to make it disappear automatically when yes is clicked. Below is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(TrackingServiceActivity.this);
alert_confirm.setMessage("Are you sure you want directions to " + data.name +"! Tracking will be suspended if it has started!");
alert_confirm.setCancelable(false).
alert_confirm.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getDirections(latitude, longitude, data.lat, data.lon);
                stopTracker();
                return;
            }
        });

alert_confirm.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });

AlertDialog alert = alert_confirm.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Where do you call .show() ?

Answer (score 0):

use this in Positive button click listner

```
getDirections(latitude, longitude, data.lat, data.lon);
stopTracker();
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `dialog.dismiss();` in Yes listener.

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        getDirections(latitude, longitude, data.lat, data.lon);
                                        stopTracker();
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        return;
                                    }
```

Comment: I tried this before and it seems to close the dialog and then reopen it again for some reason so this does not fix my issue

Comment: try `dialog.cancel();`

Comment: Please show how did you call that dialog? Maybe you called it two times ?

Comment: @Sunny, from AlertDialog documentation : `Cancel the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).`

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `dismiss();` call. Just do it like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert_confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(TrackingServiceActivity.this);
alert_confirm.setMessage("Are you sure you want directions to " + data.name +"! Tracking will be suspended if it has started!");
alert_confirm.setCancelable(false).
alert_confirm.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                getDirections(latitude, longitude, data.lat, data.lon);
                stopTracker();
                dismiss();
                return;
            }
        });

alert_confirm.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });

AlertDialog alert = alert_confirm.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
alert_confirm.setCancelable(false);
```

`[setCancelable:][1]` Sets whether the dialog is cancelable or not. Default is true.

Comment: Cancelable from outside clicks. `dismiss()` still should make the trick